# Neo4j giving error message in ubuntu

Tags: neo4j

As i am new for neo4j i have been facing the follwing errors.

1.when i start neo4j it gives the follwoing message.

WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

note :i tried to edit the file ,/etc/security/limits.conf and added
   root   soft    nofile  40000
  root   hard    nofile  40000
  but not solved

2.in the messages.log  file has multiple records like below.

2014-07-16 07:07:49.688+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 111ms [total block time: 56.805s]
2014-07-16 07:09:02.778+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 103ms [total block time: 56.908s]

The problem is some time suddently the server CPU goes high and  taking few hours to get down.Please give me a proper idea.

Thanks

Az

Answer (score 2):

1) Best practice on Ubuntu is not setting this in ´/etc/security/limits.conf`directly, instead create a file`/etc/security/limits.d/neo4j.conf` containing:

```
*   soft    nofile  40000
*   hard    nofile  40000
```

2) This is more information for you how much time is spent in GC. If a single pause gets too long it's an indication to tweak JVM settings. Stop times of 100ms is not really concerning in most cases. However the "total block time" of almost one minute might require further investigation.

Comment: Hi ,where  can we see in neo4j that a particular request takes more time .